How can I substitute over visual selection in script?
I have a script.vim file in which I'm trying to replace certain string matches.
E.g. I have in .html file a number of lines like:
<a
href="foundry-illustration/foundry-illustration.html">foundry-illustration.html</a><br />

I want to change it to:
<a
href="foundry-illustration/foundry-illustration.html">foundry illustration</a><br />

I have tried all of these in script.vim file as preliminary step:

g/href[^>]*\.html/ exe "norm! /href\<CR>/>\<CR>lv/<\<CR>h\<Esc>gv:'<,'>s/-/ /g"
g/href[^>]*\.html/ exe "norm! /href\<CR>/>\<CR>lv/<\<CR>h\<Esc>:'<,'>s/-/ /g"
g/href[^>]*\.html/ norm! /href^M/>^Mlv/<^Mh^[gv:'<,'>s/-/ /g

None work. It appears to work as expected up until the substitute command. Any ideas why?

Is there any reason for not substituting over the whole file, i.e. :%s/foo/bar/? If this isn't feasible, why resort to Visual mode instead of running :s on the line matched with :global, i.e. :g/<whatever>/s/-/ /g?

If taken at face value, the answer to your question is :help /\%V.

The script.vim is probably irrelevant, here. If so, it should be removed from the question.

I want to source this from a vim script file - I'll be doing the same thing over and over.

That part is irrelevant. Putting a command that doesn't work in a script is pointless: you should test the command in Vim's command-line first.

@romainl: I can't find any evidence for saying so now, and I may have made a mistake, but I remember a few occasions when things that worked on the commandline didn't work in a script (like what I was trying to do here). Are you saying that any commandline command will work in a script?

@Friedrich: Thanks for referencing /\%V.           That will help in future!

I'm saying that the command-line is the baseline. Make it work there before going ahead with a mapping/function/command/script/whatever.

Why processing HTML using regular expressions is a bad idea came up only yesterday and it's still a bad idea, today.
Having said that, it will work in a sufficiently simple case and may break horribly in a more complicated one.
The example line you show looks simple enough and can be transformed using the following nested substitution:
:%s/>\s*\zs\(.*\)\.html\ze\s*</\=substitute(submatch(1),'-',' ','g')/

It will run over the whole buffer and find WHATEVER.html inside inverted angle brackets.
Depending on whatever else your file contains, this may match where it shouldn't.
We then feed the captured file name (without extension) into the substitute() function to replace minuses with spaces.
Evaluating an expression through \= is explained in :help sub-replace-special.
Make sure to diff your results to find the spots where the substitution went awry.

Where do the commands go wrong?
Let's get one thing out of the way: if the commands in the question would work, they wouldn't do what you ask for.
Note that :substitute works linewise.
It operates on the entire line and would replace minuses in the href="..." attribute as well.
The '< mark (not even `<) doesn't change this behavior.
This is documented in :help :substitute.
What breaks all your commands is that you miss a <CR> at the end of the :norm! command. The final :s will never be run. Instead, the command will abort as explained in :help :normal.
Let's put a <CR> (or ^M) in and see what happens:

will fail because there's the range is specified twice: E492: Not an editor command: '<,'>'<,'>s/-/ /g
will actually run but replace all the minuses, including those in href="...".
suffers from the same error as 1.

There is one way, however, to restrict :s to the Visual selection by using \%V as explained in :help /\%V.
If you really wanted to go down this road, you could use a modified command 2:
:g/href[^>]*\.html/ exe "norm! /href\<CR>/>\<CR>lv/<\<CR>h\<Esc>gv:s/\\%V-/ /g\<CR>"

Kids, don't try this at home.

This works perfectly! Thanks. However, I would still like to know why the following doesn't work. Like I said, it appears to be OK until it reaches the substitute over visual marks part. E.g.  :g/href[^>]*\.html/ exe "norm! /href\<CR>/>\<CR>lv/<\<CR>h\<Esc>:'<,'>s/-/ /g

@Tom edited to add an explanation.

OK thanks for the added explanation. Maybe I'm being a little stupid but the docs :h '< seem to suggest it would operate on "the first line or character of the last selected visual area"

Almost: '< is the first line while `< (backtick less-than) is the first character. It doesn't matter because :s does its thing "for each line in [range]".

I would do:
%s/href="[^"]*.html">\zs[^<]*\ze/\=substitute(submatch(0),'-',' ','g')/

